# Adding an image to a UITableViewCell using plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, plist

I am getting a list of categories and showing them in a tableView using plist.I am also using plist to store the names of images and showing the images in cell.imageView.so far its working fine but if i am trying to add a new category i am getting a problem to add the image.I guess it is some problem with the array as the error am getting is about the beyond bounds.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

//Reading data from plist.
self.categoryFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Categories"];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.categoryFile])
{
    self.categoryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Categories" ofType:@"plist"];
}
self.categoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:self.categoryFile];

//get list of images from a plist
NSString *imageNames = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"ImagesNames" ofType:@"plist"];
self.imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imageNames];
[toolbar release];
[self.imagesList release];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.categoryList count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
if(!cell){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [self.categoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

//this is where am getting the error.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 1)
{
    UITextField *newCategoryName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger section = 0;
    NSInteger row = 0;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    NSString *extraContent = newCategoryName.text;
    [[self categoryList]insertObject:extraContent atIndex:row];
    [self.categoryList writeToFile:self.categoryFile atomically:YES];
    NSArray *indexPathsToInsert = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [[self tableOfCategories]insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    NSLog(@"%@",newCategoryName.text);
}
}
```

Comment: in your numberOfRowsInSection, you returned this.

    return [self.categoryList count];

and then used the `self.imagesList` as datasource in you cellForRowAtIndexPath, why so? is self.imagesList == self.categoryList?

Comment: i used self.categoryList for getting name of categories and imagesList for getting the images

Comment: that could be the reason why you are getting 'beyond bounds' exception, the returned integer in numberOfRows is not equal to the count of self.imagesList which you used in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: you can display your images in multiple section instead. in numberOfSectionsInTableView:  return the [self.categoryList count], in numberOfRowsInSection , return the count of image under specific category (using switch may do), in cellForRowAtIndexPath display the self.imageList data based on indexPath.section

Comment: its not a category of images.just the name of the category and an image for that category in the imageView.

Comment: One more question dear r u adding image names in plist under @"ImagesNames" after adding categories under category list. Update both !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your problem, I guess that you are adding Categories in plist but you are not updating ImageNames in plist. Since for number of rows you are using code like this..

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.categoryList count];
}
```

In above code since you are increasing rows according to Categories. But number of items in 
imagesList is less than categoryList because you  are increasing only Category.

Comment: i want to know that you are facing problem only after adding category. If you are not adding any category then it is working fine or not..??

Comment: even if i add a new category without this line cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; its working fine.when i am adding a new row i want some @"custom.png"   in the imageView of that row.

Comment: first NSLog both category list and image list and check that number of items in both case is same or not ??

Comment: come on chat if you are agree

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13356/discussion-between-amit-and-chandu)